find measure of set $E=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\cup_{k=n}^{\infty} E_k.$ where $E_k$ has measure $\frac{1}{k^2}$.
For $ ∈ ℕ$ , let $_$ be a measurable subset of $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure $\frac{1}{k^2}$
Define
$$E=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\cup_{k=n}^{\infty} E_k.$$ $$F=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\cap_{k=n}^{\infty} E_k$$
show that $E$ and $F$ has $0$ lebesgue measure.
now we know $\mu(F)=\mu(\liminf_k E_k)\leq \liminf_k\mu(E_k)=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}.$
this prooves $F$ has measure 0
We have $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \mu(E_k)=\liminf_{k} \mu(E_k)=\limsup_{k} \mu(E_k)=0.$$
i also know
$$\mu(\liminf_{k\to\infty}E_k) \leq \liminf_{k\to\infty} \mu(E_k)\leq \leq \limsup_{k\to\infty} \mu(E_k)\leq \mu(\limsup_{k\to\infty}E_k).$$
using all these i get $0\leq \mu(limsup_{k\to\infty}E_k).$
how to get equality.

One way to prove this is the following.
We have
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k\right)\leq \sum_{k=n}^\infty \mu(E_k)=\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac1{k^2},$$
so for all natural $n$,
$$\mu(E) \leq \mu \left(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k\right)\leq \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac1{k^2},$$ since $E\subseteq \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k$ for all $n$.
Now letting $n$ approach infinity, the RHS approaches $0$ since it equals
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{k^2},$$ and this last term is just a partial sum of the convergent series.

How you got second inequality?

@RicciTen because $E\subseteq \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty$.

I edited the answer to explain this inequality.

For the last part, one might alternatively note that for $n>1$, $0<\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\le\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{k(k-1)}=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\right)= \frac 1{n-1}$ by telescoping
